# Convert mysqli_result to mysqli or simular equivalent solution?

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to convert all MySQL codes to mysqli.

I stuck with this

```
$loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'UserLevel');
```

I tried with some mysqli_result functions but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_result() was the second most misused mysql function, next to mysql_num_rows().

It should have never been used with mysql either.
A regular fetch should be used instead of that ugly crutch

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($LoginRS);
$loginStrGroup  = $row['UserLevel'] ?? false;
```